# sqlite instr function in not working in some cases

Tags: string, sqlite, position

In Sqlite we have table1 with column column1
there are 4 rows with following values for column1

```
(p1,p10,p11,p20)

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;
CREATE TABLE table1(column1 NVARCHAR);
INSERT INTO table1 (column1) values ('p1'),('p10'),('p11'),('p20');
Select instr(',p112,p108,p124,p204,p11,p1124,p1,p10,p20,',','+column1+',') from table1;
```

We have to get the position of each value of column1 in the given string:
,p112,p108,p124,p204,p11,p1124,p1,p10,p20,

the query

```
Select instr(',p112,p108,p124,p204,p11,p1124,p1,p10,p20,',column1) from table1;
```

returns values 
    (2,7,2,17)

which is not what we want

the query

```
Select instr(',p112,p108,p124,p204,p11,p1124,p1,p10,p20,',','+column1+',') from table1;
```

returns 9 for all rows - 
it turned out that it is the position of first "0" symbol ???

Howe we can get the exact positions of column1 in the given string in sqlite ??

Comment: If you put each of the values in the CSV string in a table row with position & value columns this is simple to do with a JOIN.

Comment: the string is being build externally, and it is different for each query.

Comment: this query is working well in MSSQL with charindex

Comment: I wonder why the second query returns the position of symbol "0" ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **SQLite** the concatenation operator is `||` and not `+` (like **SQL Server**), so do this:

```
Select instr(',p112,p108,p124,p204,p11,p1124,p1,p10,p20,',',' || column1 || ',') from table1;
```

What you did with your code was number addition which resulted to `0`, because none of the string operands could succesfully be converted to number,
so `instr()` was searching for `'0'` and found it always at position `9` of the string:`',p112,p108,p124,p204,p11,p1124,p1,p10,p20,'`.